# How to achive this in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a pyspark dataframe `df` :-

| SKU | Store | Flag | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 33000120304 | 629138 | 1 | 20210507 |
| 33000009746 | 629138 | 0 | 20210129 |
| 50000441489 | 629138 | 1 | 20210511 |
| 22000020680 | 187367 | 0 | 20220210 |
| 41419714737 | 187367 | 1 | 20210628 |
| 50000577980 | 176129 | 0 | 20220225 |
| 50000001607 | 633782 | 1 | 20210419 |
| 50000001607 | 633782 | 1 | 20210419 |
| 50000001608 | 633782 | 1 | 20210419 |

I want to get the distinct count of `SKU` presence (indicated by `Flag`) for the max(latest) `Date` for every store. example :=

| store | count_distinct_sku |
| --- | --- |
| 629138 | 1 |
| 187367 | 0 |
| 176129 | 0 |
| 633782 | 2 |

How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Window functions:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
    ('33000120304','629138','1','20210507')
    ,('33000009746','629138','0','20210129')
    ,('50000441489','629138','1','20210511')
    ,('22000020680','187367','0','20220210')
    ,('41419714737','187367','1','20210628')
    ,('50000577980','176129','0','20220225')
    ,('50000001607','633782','1','20210419')
    ,('50000001607','633782','1','20210419')
    ,('50000001608','633782','1','20210419')
    ],
    ['SKU','Store','Flag','Date']
).withColumn('Date', F.to_date(F.col('Date'), 'yyyyMMdd'))


w = Window.partitionBy("Store").orderBy(F.desc('Date'))

df_res = df\
    .withColumn('max_date', F.max(F.col('Date')).over(w))\
    .filter((F.col('Date') == F.col('max_date')))\
    .filter(F.col('Flag')==1)\
    .groupBy('Store').agg(F.countDistinct("SKU").alias('count_distinct_sku'))

df\
.select('Store')\
.dropDuplicates()\
.join(df_res, on='Store', how='left')\
.fillna(0)\
.show()

# +------+------------------+
# | Store|count_distinct_sku|
# +------+------------------+
# |629138|                 1|
# |187367|                 0|
# |176129|                 0|
# |633782|                 2|
# +------+------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, testing. We do not need to convert Date to date format for `max` to work?

Comment: That'd be wise. Code updated.

Comment: does it matter though?

Comment: No, it will be ordered just like a number

Comment: right it makes sense only because yyyymmdd format

Comment: Could you answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74570168/how-to-achieve-this-dynamic-alloction-in-pyspark