# How to update a column conditionally pyspark

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a pyspark dataframe `df` :-

| status | Flag |
| --- | --- |
| present | 1 |
| present | 0 |
| na | 1 |
| Void | 0 |
| present | 1 |
| notpresent | 0 |
| present | 0 |
| present | 0 |
| ok | 1 |

I want to update the `Flag` as 1 wherever we have status is   `present` or `ok` :-

Expected :-

| status | Flag |
| --- | --- |
| present | 1 |
| present | 1 |
| na | 1 |
| Void | 0 |
| present | 1 |
| notpresent | 0 |
| present | 1 |
| present | 1 |
| ok | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so using `withColumn` and a check using `when`. You recreate the Flag column setting it to 1 if status is ok or present, otherwise you keep the existing value.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col, lit

data = [
    ('present', 0),
    ('ok', 0),
    ('present', 1),
    ('void', 0),
    ('na', 1),
    ('notpresent', 0)
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['status', 'Flag'])
df.show()

df.withColumn('Flag', when(col('status').isin(['ok', 'present']), lit(1)).otherwise(col('Flag'))).show()
```

Output

```
+----------+----+
|    status|Flag|
+----------+----+
|   present|   0|
|        ok|   0|
|   present|   1|
|      void|   0|
|        na|   1|
|notpresent|   0|
+----------+----+

+----------+----+
|    status|Flag|
+----------+----+
|   present|   1|
|        ok|   1|
|   present|   1|
|      void|   0|
|        na|   1|
|notpresent|   0|
+----------+----+
```

Comment: could you answer this if possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74445418/how-to-achive-this-in-pyspark-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way

```
df.withColumn('Flag', col('status').isin(['ok', 'present']).astype('int')).show()

+----------+----+
|    status|Flag|
+----------+----+
|   present|   1|
|        ok|   1|
|   present|   1|
|      void|   0|
|        na|   1|
|notpresent|   0|
+----------+----+
```