# How to achieve this dynamic alloction in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a dataframe `store_df` :-

| store | ID | Div |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 637 | 4000000970 | Pac |
| 637 | 4000000435 | Pac |
| 637 | 4000055542 | Pac |
| 637 | 4000042206 | Pac |
| 637 | 4000014114 | Pac |

I have another dataframe `final_list` :-

| Div | ID | Rank | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pac | 4000000970 | 1 | A |
| Pac | 4000000432 | 2 | A |
| Pac | 4000000405 | 3 | A |
| Pac | 4000042431 | 4 | A |
| Pac | 2200028596 | 5 | B |
| Pac | 4000000032 | 6 | A |
| Pac | 2200028594 | 7 | B |
| Pac | 4000014114 | 8 | B |
| Pac | 2230001789 | 9 | D |
| Pac | 2200001789 | 10 | C |
| Pac | 2200001787 | 11 | D |

Yet another dataframe `max_df` :-

| store | MAX_A | MAX_B | MAX_C | MAX_D | N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 637 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 5 |

I want to add columns `Add_A`, `Add_B`,`Add_C`, `Add_D` in `max_df` such that this criteria is satisfied :-
1.)`ID` in `store_df` should be removed from `final_list` for that store based on `Div`
2.)Post removing,`N`number of `ID` is to be picked from `final_list` in order of `Rank` such that it does not overshoot `MAX_A`,`MAX_B`,`MAX_C`,`MAX_D` for respective `Category` and this should happen dynamically for all stores in `store_df`.Note :- `N` will always be <= sum of `MAX` category columns.So we need to pick `N` from `final_list` so that for each category the count does not exceed `MAX` .In this example its equal .For example above post eliminating `4000000970` & `4000014114` and do a group by count of `final_list` we get 4 for `A`,2 for `B`,1 for `C`,2 for `D` but as should not allocate above `MAX_A,MAX_B,MAX_C,MAX_D` respectively we have to allocate this way:-

Expected output for above `max_df` :-

1.)`max_df`

| store | MAX_A | MAX_B | MAX_C | MAX_D | N | Add_A | Add_B | Add_C | Add_D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 637 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 5 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

2.)A pyspark dataframe `result_df` with the `ID` s picked in order of `Rank` for all the stores:-

| store | ID | New_Rank | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 637 | 4000000432 | 1 | A |
| 637 | 4000000405 | 2 | A |
| 637 | 4000042431 | 3 | A |
| 637 | 2200001789 | 4 | C |

=>(Example 2) :- `final_list` :-

| Div | ID | Rank | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pac | 4000000970 | 1 | A |
| Pac | 4000000432 | 2 | A |
| Pac | 4000000405 | 3 | A |
| Pac | 4000042431 | 4 | A |
| Pac | 2200028596 | 5 | B |
| Pac | 4000000032 | 6 | A |
| Pac | 2200028594 | 7 | B |
| Pac | 4000014114 | 8 | B |
| Pac | 2230001789 | 9 | D |
| Pac | 2200001789 | 10 | C |
| Pac | 2200001786 | 11 | C |

Expected output :-

| store | MAX_A | MAX_B | MAX_C | MAX_D | N | Add_A | Add_B | Add_C | Add_D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 637 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 5 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 0 |

`result_df` :-

| store | ID | New_Rank | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 637 | 4000000432 | 1 | A |
| 637 | 4000000405 | 2 | A |
| 637 | 4000042431 | 3 | A |
| 637 | 2200001789 | 4 | C |
| 637 | 2200001786 | 5 | C |

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession,Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import mean, min, max,count,row_number,lit,udf,col
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# creating the session
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
 
# schema creation by passing list
store_df  = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(Store=637,ID=4000000970, Div='Pac'),
    Row(Store=637,ID=4000000435, Div='Pac'),
    Row(Store=637,ID=4000055542, Div='Pac'),
    Row(Store=637,ID=4000042206, Div='Pac'),
    Row(Store=637,ID=4000014114, Div='Pac'),
])

final_list   = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(Div='Pac',ID=4000000970, Rank=1,Category='A'),
    Row(Div='Pac',ID=4000000432, Rank=2,Category='A'),
    Row(Div='Pac',ID=4000000405, Rank=3,Category='A'),
    Row(Div='Pac',ID=4000042431, Rank=4,Category='A'),
    Row(Div='Pac',ID=2200028596, Rank=5,Category='B'),
    Row(Div='Pac',ID=4000000032, Rank=6,Category='A'),
    Row(Div='Pac',ID=2200028594, Rank=7,Category='B'),
    Row(Div='Pac',ID=4000014114, Rank=8,Category='B'),
    Row(Div='Pac',ID=2230001789, Rank=9,Category='D'),
    Row(Div='Pac',ID=2200001789, Rank=10,Category='C'),
    Row(Div='Pac',ID=2200001787, Rank=11,Category='D'),

])

max_df  =  spark.createDataFrame([
          Row(Store=637,MAX_A=3, MAX_B=0,MAX_C=2,MAX_D=0,N=5),])

Updated_final_list = final_list.join(store_df, ["Div","ID"], "left_anti")
Updated_final_list.show()

# Count each Category
Category_count = ( Updated_final_list.groupBy("Category")
        .pivot("Category")
        .count() )
Category_count = Category_count.fillna(value=0)

Category_count = Category_count.agg({i:'max' for i in 
                                  Category_count.columns[1:]})

for i in Category_count.columns:
  Category_count = Category_count.withColumnRenamed(i, i.split('(')[1][0])

# The following code is to create id to merge max df and Category_count
max_df = max_df.withColumn("M_ID", lit(1))
Category_count = Category_count.withColumn("M_ID", lit(1))

max_df1 = max_df.join(Category_count,['M_ID'],'inner')

# Calculate number of id needs to be created for each category
@udf(returnType=IntegerType())

def max_id_cal(A,B):
  if B <=A:
    return B
  else:
    return B-(B-A)

max_col = [i for i in max_df.columns if i.startswith('MAX')]
for c in max_col:
  max_df1 = max_df1.withColumn(c.split('_')[1], 
                            max_id_cal(max_df1[c],c.split('_')[1]))

# New Rank is created for each category
windowDept = Window.partitionBy("Category").orderBy(col("Rank").asc())
Updated_final_list1=Updated_final_list.withColumn("Rank1",row_number()
                                                  .over(windowDept))

# Filter number records for each category
idx = 0
max_col = [i for i in max_df.columns if i.startswith('MAX')]
for c in max_col:
  max_value = max_df1.select(c.split('_')[1]).collect()[0][0]

  if idx == 0:
    df=Updated_final_list1.filter((col("Category")==c.split('_')[1]) & 
        (col("Rank1") <= max_value))
  else:
    df2=Updated_final_list1.filter((col("Category")==c.split('_')[1]) & 
              (col("Rank1") <= max_value))
    df = df.union(df2)
    
  idx +=1


df = df.drop("Rank")
df= df.withColumnRenamed('Rank1', 'Rank')

df.show()
```

Comment: This is not working . could you plese re-check. Is there a way to do it in pyspark without using udf functions?